# Firebase functions - RealtimeDatabse Triggers Pick 2 children and place them in other node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am have a node in firebase realtime database '`zSearchingUsers`', in which all the searching users gets in which user end application when they start searching, they look as shown in the photo:

[image: Searching users]

Now what I want to do is to define a firebase function(javascript), which will listens to `zSearchingUsers` node and whenever 2 or more users comes, it pick a pair of them and place them in `zPairedUsers`, in this format:

[image: Paired Users]

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sounds feasible. What's the problem you ran into while implementing this?

Comment: This is for random video chat application, in which Users will come online and I will make pairs(2 users in a pair) and make a room for them(WebRTC) and send them to the room, I needed this algorithm so that user will get registered in zSearchingUsers and will listens to the zPairedUsers

Comment: I know you are official guy from Google Firebase, can you help me out with that? maybe any other way(inside realtime database firebase), I will be really thankful, I am really stuck!

Comment: The user-case and requirement are clear enough. What isn't clear is what you've already done yourself. It's unlikely (though not impossible) that somebody will write the entire code for you to translate the use-case into a working app. It's much more likely that somebody will help you, if you show what you've already implemented yourself and where you got stuck.

Comment: No no I already have done everything, even my app is published, but previous algorithm(which I did at user end in java) is causing problems, I am not known to javascript much and functions, I just need a single function script to do the operations I described in my question, I asked you do that only for me, the script for the functions, I followed your other answers but I am having error 'undefined property "ref" in that!

Comment: I will appreciate it sir, please!

Comment: Hey Puf, please check my code add added that to my question, Can you help me now? this counts the number of children, the next I need to get them paired in zPairedUser

Comment: Thanks for that update, it looks like you made some great progress. 1) Can you show (like `console.log()`) what the value of `listcounter` is? 2) I don't see you loading the data that needs to be matched. Is that in `change.after`? Or somewhere else? Can you `console.log` that data too, and add the JSON to your question?

Comment: Hey puf, check Update 2, and the error, I am very close i think!

Comment: Good to hear that you got further. It seems that you're missing some return statements now, which means that Cloud Functions has no way to know when all the asynchronous read and write operations are done. Please search for the two error messages you get, as they occur regularly and have been answered a few times already.